# How to include files in PHP Phalcon controllers

Tags: php, include, phalcon

my file structure for phalcon is something like this

--app 
-----controllers 
-----models 
-----views 
-----functions 
-----libraries

where functions and libraries folder contains some third party scripts like facebook log in etc, when I include the script in my controller classes, I did

include "../functions/facebook.php"

but it gives a file not found error.

How should I include files in the controller classes?

Comment: This thing is in the `controller` directory? It seems obvious, but I don't give 1 point new users the benefit of the doubt: does this file `facebook.php` exist?

Comment: Can you give us the exact location of your controller file that is having problems doing the include and the exact location of `facebook.php`?

Comment: controller file is in app/controllers/SessionController.php
facebook.php is in app/functions/facebook.php

Comment: actually adding a global __DIR__ in the include directory helps finding the file. But the functions included in the php script is not included as it gives Fatal error: Call to undefined function foo().

Comment: found my error, in my php file I did <? instead of <?php, so it didn't read it as php script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you should be [using an autoloader](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/loader.html) Phalcon provides for automatically loading classes.

For non-classes, did you try using full path?

```
include __DIR__ . "/../functions/facebook.php";
```

Comment: The file is found, but the function within the php script is not included. For example, in my test.php I have a function foo(), I included __DIR__."/../functions/test.php" but it gives Fatal error: Call to undefined function foo().

Comment: found my error, in my php file I did <? instead of <?php, so it didn't read it as php script.